# CakePHP 1.3: How can I check how many visitors I have in my site at a specific time?

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I want to get some ideas on how to handle this. How can I check, real time, how many visitors I have surfing my site at a specific time with CakePHP? Should I rely on Sessions, or should I setup a function that pulls data from a DB table, or is there any better way?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to set your Session management to Database, so Cake stores all sessions in the database.
Then count the number of active sessions in the database table. You'll have to make your own definition of 'active', but you *could* (for example) look at the `modified` value of the records and say that a modification in the past 3 or 5 minutes means an active session.